# Move background relative to an object

Tags: background, 2d, processing, box2d

This is a Processing 2.x related question but you can give a general answer and I will translate that into processing sketch.
I want to move my background relative to an object that i have made in box2d and is following a trajectile path. I want that object to remain inside the sketch and not to go past the width of the sketch. how can I do that?
This is what I have tried: (The image displayed is a large image, 4 times the width of the sketch)

```
void Display(Gulli gulli) {
    imageMode(CENTER);
    if (gulli.isMoving()) {
      Vec2 gulli_pos = gulli.getPosition();
      gulli_pos.mulLocal(-1);  // to move background in opposite direction of the object
      pushMatrix();
      translate(gulli_pos.x+width*1.63, +height/2+gulli_pos.y);
      image(img, pos.x, pos.y);
      popMatrix();
    } else {
      pushMatrix();
      translate(width*1.5, -height/2);
      image(img, pos.x, pos.y);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You'll have much better luck if you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a snippet of code. Note that this should not be your entire project, just enough for us to experiment with.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Sample]

I did something like that ones, let me try to explain it whit this simple drawing.

The black square is the background image, the grey one the sketch screen of Processing and the red ball your moving object.
The idea it's that while the distance between the side of the backImage and the side of the screen is greater than 0, you move the background image using the same speed than the ball, but in the opposite direction. Ones this condition changes you move the ball normally.

Hope this help's.
Regards
Jose